# Where should i put auth token fetch logic for Alamofire using RequestAdapter?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

So I'm using `Alamofire` 4.5, a new pattern of `RequestAdapter` and `RequestRetrier`. In all of the sample code, the adapter is used to simply append headers of auth tokens. The retrier is used to fetch a new token in case of an error.

However I want to put in logic to fetch a new token before it hits the retrier logic. Why waste a request that will 100% generate an error? Ideally this would go in the adapter (ie. check if we have valid token, not fetch new one, then continue the original request.)

I'm wondering that this would create an infinite loop within `RequestAdapter`, or there is a better way to do this with `Alamofire`.

Thanks